# Why was my question ill-received?

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question, question-quality

I write this after wanting to ask another question and seeing the popup that I might get banned from asking questions because my previous questions were received badly. (0 votes, 0 votes, -1 votes)

This is my last question from today:
[Ellipse not updating in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49028676/ellipse-not-updating-in-wpf)

I tried to be very specific, I put research into the matter beforehand. Explained everything (I believe) well, put code in it, example pictures and the solution, although simple was (I believe) no so extremely basic that it might be the cause.

*Also I believe to be at least a bit able to write good questions because I am a rather active member in the Interpersonal Skills SE with good reputation.*

**So why was this question received badly?**

PS: I write this not to rant but to understand the matter to be able to write better questions in the future.

Comment: Just looking at the question, it's very specific and not likely to get many votes as being "useful". Your description of the problem is still a vague "does not work". It may have been initially down voted for lack of code, not sure. Finally, really long questions are more difficult to fully understand and appreciate. Many users skip those and move on to answer more concise questions.

Comment: It's a cumulative thing...you have 30+ questions only 5 of which have a positive score...so that's not a good record. It may not be **this** question that's the issue...it's **all the others**.

Comment: @Paulie_D Yeah but what should i do against that? This is the only one with the negative score, and i cannot influence if people really like my question. I have a problem that needs to be fixed. Try to ask a question as good as possible, but ultimately i cannot influence if people resonate with the question :/

Comment: Not having a negative score does not mean they were well received. If a question has no votes...it's not a positive.

Comment: You know, with MVVM all you would need would be a Canvas, a data template, one view model, one model and one ICommand that does the L,R,U or D transform on the model. You could do that with less than 100 LOC and probably the same number of LOX. You're doing this the *haaaaaard* way.  Go search for "shape canvas mvvm" or "rectangle canvas mvvm" or "circle canvas mvvm" for an example. There are a lot of them out there.

Comment: Quote: "you can add as answer and i can accept that if you want :)".  No, **you** can add that answer.  You started it, you now know how to finish it.  If you are not interested in that then just click Delete.

Comment: *I have a problem that needs to be fixed* Sorry, but that's not the purpose of SO. If the question isn't sufficient to also help future readers here, it shouldn't be here. SO doesn't exist solely to fix your *problem that needs to be fixed*. A question needs to be suitable to add to the knowledge base for others; if it happens to also solve your problem, that's a bonus, not a privilege or right.

Comment: *"I tried to be very specific"* - Indeed, you did. **Way** too specific, making the question helpful to only a single visitor to this site. What you need to do is to abstract the essence of the issue, then ask about that generalized issue. It would then be shorter, more concise, and potentially helpful to a large audience. As asked, the question is hardly any better than all the other *"Please debug my code for me"* questions.

Comment: Besides, a more professional image on your [Developer Story](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/7967793) might help, too. This place is visited by professionals, from their workplace. They expect content to be SFW.

Comment: @IInspectable How is the picture of a person with headphones on not SFW`?

Comment: @KenWhite As stated already in another comment. For me SO is a tool to solve my problem nothing more nothing less. I try to conform to the rules and norms of this site as best as possible, but i do this not to better the site but to increase my chances of receiving help. A very selfish motivation i know but thats how it is. A tool :)

Comment: Did you not follow the link I posted? I fail to see any headphones.

Comment: Ohh sorry this one xD haha

Comment: Stop trying to please everyone. They down-voted you? Forget 'em.

Comment: @KenWhite as has been demonstrated many times on Meta, you (and I ) are in the minority. According to SO corporate and to many answerers, SO is indeed a tool to solve people's problems. All that high talk about accumulation of long-term generally useful knowledge is  long past.

Comment: @Arkadiy: I'll still work toward that goal. It keeps my close and downvotes from going to waste. You know, *use 'em or lose 'em*. :-)

Comment: So continue to treat the site that way (as a tool that you show no respect for), but don't expect us to not treat you like any other user and close or downvote poor questions. Continue long enough, and you won't have to worry about it for long.

Comment: @KenWhite & Arkady  This reminds me of someone building a huge huge library with knowledge from all around the world, but allwoing noone to use it. I still dont get why this was a poor question because: if a question is badly described so noone can help because they dont understand whats going on is one thing. But thinking a question is bad because its so specific it might only help this person is imho no problem at all. Why is it bad? If it helps 1 person, thats 1 person more than none at all if i didnt post the question. If it helps more, the better.

Comment: If the answer won't benefit others in the future, it isn't useful here at all. If you want answers to problems that are specific to you, hire a contractor and pay them to provide them. If that doesn't work for you, then hope that you can phrase the question in a way that makes it of use to others, or suffer through getting your posts closed. And as I said, continue long enough and it won't be an issue, because enough poor questions end up in a question ban and you can't ask at all any longer. As far as your *not allowing anyone to use it*, that's nonsense.

Comment: (continued) We allow everyone to use it. But just like building a real brick and mortar library, we only accept quality donations. We don't let people use it as a landfill or storage for their personal diaries, and we don't allow people to tear out the pages that are helpful; we expect them to leave content that helps other people.

Comment: I understand you deleting the question to avoid the meta effect, but please provide a screenshot, so everyone can see what this question is about.

Comment: It's takes analytical and research ability more than interpersonal skill to ask a good question. I can't speak for everyone else, but I personally would much prefer an interesting problem involving a well-constructed MCVE that contains little more than "y code gif dis outpoot?" above a well-articulated, properly-explained question that contains a whole bunch of unnecessary code / doesn't show an attempt at debugging / lacks the actual output / contain code not reproducing the described behaviour / has whatever other fundamental technical problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66556199/why-do-i-get-an-entrypointnotfoundexception-error-when-using-net-6-0-but-not-w?noredirect=1#comment127863219_66556199 See my post here? Now see the comments, there is a meta. Look at how the responded to me regarding why my post was ill recieved. It will explain a lot.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I don't know enough about c# in order to actually judge the content of your question so I will refrain from voting on it, but here is my impression when looking at it.

1) The question contains a very complex example for a (relatively) simple issue. It takes quite a bit of reading to get to the core problem, which is that you want to repaint an object upon some event occurring. You could make a much easier to digest example by taking out the grid and movement, and just try to make an object paint itself on one space, then given an arbitrary event, the object paints itself on another.

The benefits of doing this are two fold: The problems is isolated (So we aren't confused if the WASD button presses are causing anything or if something with the grid is going wrong, we know we're focused on the repainting of the object and we can easily focus on the important thing you're asking), and also the question then becomes applicable not only to people who want to move an object through a grid with the arrow keys, but rather it's applicable to anyone who wants to repaint an object.

2) Before the edit, there wasn't enough information for the example to be complete and verifiable.

This may seem to contradict my previous point, since now I'm saying didn't provide enough information, even though at first I said you provided too much. But allow me to explain:

With the information you gave at first, another user couldn't copy/paste your code and have a working example to fiddle with, they would have to add in other things that were missing. So a person wanting to help you is left wondering if the error might be in some other part of your code that we can't see.

However, by including all your other code, the question just became that more cumbersome, with so many moving parts that it's hard to know where to start looking for the answer.

That's the beauty of reducing your issue to something much more simple. If you just have some sort of generic event instead of all the wasd movement commands, and if you're just worried about painting the object in one place and then repainting it in another without all the code calculating where it lands, then you can make a complete and verifiable example that someone can run with a minimal amount of code in the question.

---

My suggestion:

Figure out a really easy to code event, something that's less than 3 lines if possible. You might be able to do that with a button or keypress, but make sure it's simple.

Then, draw your shape at a certain point, and make the result of the event draw it at another predetermined point. This will get rid of all the calculations because we're just looking at two certain points, where we start and where we want to be.

Now that you have your simplistic GUI just drawing one thing twice based on the one event, try to figure out why in this minimal example the object isn't redrawing.

Edit your question and swap the complicated movement/keypress example for this really simple one, with the entire code there so that someone else can run it, and an explanation of what commands you've tried to get it to repaint and what results are different from what you expected the commands to do.

If you write your question like this, it will be simple and to the point, easy for an answerer to understand and help you, and on top of that, when another person is having the same issue and cannot redraw their object, whatever event they may be using or calculations of where to redraw the object, they will be able to read your question and find their answer.

Comment: For further reading about how to prepare a good example for an issue, see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I was just about to sit down and rewrite my question and then noticed that by making up a simple example simply about the ellipse and the drawing of it, my problem could not have been solved because the problem was the instancing of the method :/ So sadly for the same problem to still exist there is no other way as to leave it as it is. I willl leave it, and after some time delete it, so that this question has relevance for some time at least

Comment: *"The benefits of doing this are two fold"* *Three*-fold: A lot of the time, going through the process of building an MCVE reveals the problem. (Almost always, for me; YMMV.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Indeed, it is a core element of debugging, and one of the reasons we get so pissed off at people not providing a MCVE is that it indicates they _haven't done their debugging yet_!

Answer (score -14):

The problem divides into two parts:

1. the part that is not under your control
2. the part you are able to learn and draw consequences from

**Let me begin with part 1 because it is more complex:**

The longer a specific field of knowledge exists, the more probable it is that questions get asked repeatedly. The closer a question is to the beginner level, the greater the probability of such a "trivial" question is, just because beginners are more likely to ask questions. What aggravates this problem is, that beginners are less able to judge whether their specific problem is similar to another question that has already been asked in the past. Among other things they often just don't know the official technical terms yet, that would enable them to find past questions of similar content.

This does not yet answer the question why there is so much downvoting and negative discouraging speech here. In my experience, fatal social dynamics most often develops out of the wrong incentives being set by authorities. When I read through the newest questions on SO for example, it happens so often (say for almost every second question) that the majority of those who comment obviously haven't even fully read the question. They often just react spontaneously to certain discredited keywords or combinations thereof. It has been so often that I was able to see that a question was actually quite easy to answer, because I took the time to understand what the OP meant. Many people don't do that. They express their confusion, which is actually caused by their own attention deficit.

Why is that so? Well, because of the wrong incentives! If they get the impression that quality control is the main objective here, they will just behave like any old business economist, putting the red pen here, firing somebody there. Taken together with many people's job experience it's not hard to conjecture that this kind of behavior is due to preemptive obedience.

On the other hand we all know that the most successful driver of any collective effort is intrinsic motivation. But why then doesn't this principle become prevalent? Because answerers are not incentivised for motivating others but for getting the highest reputation scores. You may say that this amounts to the same, but it does not. Anyone with sufficient social skills will notice whether somebody just answers to get the reputation points quickly or if he is trying to be truly helpful. Eventually the difference lies in the quality of the answer. If I only get answers of the first type, I will finally give them the green checkmark even if the answer does not actually help me, just because I am hoping that my vote will encourage better answers among bad answers. Actually it could be subject to discussion whether my vote will induce any improvement into the not that bad answerers at all. Hopefully they don't mutate into people who prefer to downvote new questions just because they are not able to give helpful answers. So all in all superficial incentives im combination with mediocre personalities will lead to slowly degrading quality due to intrinsic demotivation.

And last but not least there is yet another phenomenon called adverse selection in economic science. If the average revenue of a set of deals undercuts the average quality of the dealt goods or services, better offerings will gradually leave the market - because they just can't get the revenue they deserve - until a new equilibrium between average price and quality has been reached, ie. inferior goods have accumulated in the market. Means: if negative, discouraging people discount positive, encouraging people, the latter will retreat gradually.

**Now to part 2, what you can do about it:**

Short answer: nothing. Long answer: get yourself a thick skin. Work on believing in nice, helpful people, who may even be the silent majority. And most of all it is a matter of conducted attention. Consider all the unsolicited admonitions, rants and downvotes as social noise. Force yourself to notice the good quality answerers, who just help instead of linking to the site policies on every new post. But that is hard work. It is not difficult to see that I am aware of me being not the most suitable person for such a task. But there are many people who have a natural talent for it. Maybe you are one of them, who just have to notice that it is not your fault. You don't have to ask yourself what you have done wrong, just continue with what you would have been doing if nothing negative had happened.

Comment: I disagree. Downvoting is not an attack to the OP, it's just that the question itself is bad (either it had been asked before - in that case the OP had not research enough, or it's off-topic)

Comment: There is no point in having multiple identical answers to duplicate question - that way, the useful information are scattered, overall it's harder for people to search for information.

Comment: This answer looks like a rant against downvoters.

Comment: @user202729: I have seen so many questions that are not bad and get downvoted anyway. I have seen even some that got a duplicate suggestion that was utterly unrelated. I have seen many comments that  revealed that the user has not even bothered to read beyond the title. My answer just tries to explain why this is so and why I think it will degrade more and more.

Comment: Citation (some example comment/question that you mentioned) please? If you think that something is wrong, flag it for moderator attention, or ask it on meta. I won't believe you if you don't have a proof.

Comment: @user202729: as to redundant questions: I see absolutely no need to delete anything in times of abundant storage. The only thing that's needed is to prefer questions that get upvoted in the search results. If you have children you might already know that it is futile to try to fight against undesired behavior. You have to encourage desired behavior, nothing else. And this is where a parent can prove to the child that he/she is more experienced than the child.

Comment: That's not the problem - in fact, [se] keeps everything includes spam posts, all revisions of all posts, deleted comments, etc. The reasons why duplicated questions need to be closed is to avoid good answers being scattered.

Comment: @user202729: sorry, I don't have to prove anything to you, let alone scientific chains of evidence. If you disagree, that's okay for me. It was just a well-intentioned offer.

Comment: As I said, you won't scatter anything if you sufficiently prefer the good over the bad. Technically, negative votes just move the zero-point. But socially the effects are devastating.

Comment: @oliver The fact that you consider it "socially devastating" for someone to know that they've done something wrong, rather than to be told they did a good job *when they have done something wrong* says a lot about you.   That you want people feel good *when they are acting harmfully and making the site a worse place* means that you are intentionally and knowingly going out of your way to make the site worse.

Comment: @Servy: I get the feeling that you take this personally. You don't need to because I don't know you and I have zero motivation to run you down, or any other honorable, renowned member of this community. In principle you and me want the same thing: make this site better by keeping people from doing a bad job. Our only difference lies in the definition of a "good job" and what it means to do a bad job. I still don't see why discouraging people (knowingly or not) helps them develop their full potential. I would call that a leadership concept from the Victorian Age...

Comment: @oliver So how does lying to people and telling them that they're doing a good job when they are doing a bad job going to help them develop their potential?  That's not leadership.  It's bad for them, because they're never going to be able to improve, and it is of course even worse for everyone else, who has to deal with the harmful behavior that they're being actively encouraged to continue.  Yes, I supposed I do take it personally when people go around intentionally making this community worse just to make themselves feel better.

Comment: @Servy: where did I say something about lying to someone? Not dramatizing mistakes is not the same thing as praising them. But by punishing somebody (that's what downvoting actually is) you are insinuating that a person is not able to learn and notice of himself that a lack of success or praise is already a sign of his/her failure. You are driving him towards low self-esteem and so to perpetuate the pattern of submission and preemptive obedience. This has a slight smack of totalitarianism.

Comment: @Oliver Downvoting someone is not punishment. Reputation only exists on Stack Overflow: There is no real world bearing or actual punishment associated with it. A downvote alerts the user that their question/answer is not useful, poorly written, or in some way off topic, so that that person can make it better, for their own sake (getting the answer they want), and for the sake of Stack Overflow. Punishment is no where entered into the concept. If you believe downvotes are punishment or abusive, then you have a very poor concept of the purpose of the Stack Exchange Network.

Comment: @oliver "where did I say something about lying to someone?" You said you like to upvote/accept answers that aren't helpful just to make people feel good.  That's lying to them.  It's you indicating to them that you think it's useful when you don't actually think that it's useful.  And universally refusing to tell someone when they've done something wrong is, not quite as bad, but still bad.  No, people can't (and shouldn't) assume that no feedback means that it's bad.  It means no one has formed an opinion on the post.  Lots of posts just *don't get evaluated*; that doesn't mean they're bad.

Comment: When a post *is* bad, indicating as much is a very useful signal to the author that they have problems and need to work on fixing them.  If they don't want to, that's their choice, but they were given the useful feedback to act on.

Comment: @Servy: okay you were referring to my own behavior as lying. Yeah, that may be. But that was just a side note, not as an example that my spontaneous reactions were a good example. My bad for mentioning this in my line argument.

Comment: @Davy M: may I invite you to read the definition of the term punishment at wikipedia? I don't want to do you wrong, but I can't help but suspect that stating something so obviously wrong like "downvoting is not punishment" shows a good deal of bias on your side.

Comment: "Punishment (Noun): the infliction or imposition of a penalty as retribution for an offense." Take it one step further: "Penalty: a disadvantage or unpleasant experience suffered as the result of an action or circumstance". Okay, please explain to me how a downvote is a penalty or something that is suffered. A downvote is communication, a downvote is at its core a good thing because it is communicating to the author that there is something wrong with their post, however the downvote carries no infliction of a disadvantage or other idea of punishment.

Comment: It's not my misunderstanding of Punishment, it's your misunderstanding of what a downvote actually is. You are seeing it like an attack on you, like someone is causing you harm or degrading you, but that is not what a downvote is. When you understand that, you will be able to benefit from downvotes and make your questions and answers better. A downvote is a constructive criticism.

Comment: Take for example this question you have answered. The person was downvoted, so they asked how to make their question better. They got an answer, and as they tried to make a better question, doing so led them to their answer that they needed. The downvotes were a blessing to this person, not a punishment, because the person received it constructively instead of taking an "I'm being attacked" mindset.

Comment: @Davy M: it may sound cynical, but let's just take our disagreement with a little humor: applying the established practice on this site, your question about why downvoting is punishment would get a lot of downvotes, and probably, just probably someone will lower himself to direct you to the "how to ask page", pointing out that you should first read about the foundations of the subject or simply say that your question does not make sense to him. Understand? I am not just talking about a game with specific rules, but rather about the spirit of (some of) its players.

Comment: Actually, it would get closed as opinion based, because I wasn't asking why downvoting is punishment, I already explained that it is not. My request was for *you* to explain it, so my question was asking for your opinion to try to understand where your disconnect between receiving a downvote and understanding what it means. So, no, I don't understand, since you haven't answered.

Comment: Though from your reply I understand a bit more about your misconceptions: you see SO community members as people who believe themselves high and mighty, who have to "Come down" to answer a normal person's question. You see standard practice meaning downvoting things that you believe to be on topic en masse, so that shows you do not understand the rules that the downvoted posts are violating or the reason why the post is ultimately not useful. You also see SO as a game, so perhaps you are overly focused on the points incentives, and that's why you see downvotes taking away points as punishment.

Comment: But the point of all this isn't to judge or insult you, it's to attempt to understand what you need in order to realize that downvotes are a positive thing, they mean a person cared enough about what you wrote to inform you that it is wrong. Learning how to ask good questions is an amazing benefit that comes from participating on any of the SE sites, but it takes work; my first questions were downvoted too. And that helped me look for errors, understand what I did wrong, and better my understanding of how to ask a good question: on SE or in Real Life. I want you to receive these benefits.

Comment: Davy, we won't settle this because we simply have different points of view. I understand very well what you mean, but I simply do not think it is true. This is not just a machine, that you're programming with rules carefully designed to help people learn (which is honorable enough). It is a dynamic system that has only worked in the past because there was abundant energy ("a lot of good questions"). We will witness many things fail in the field of information technology in the years to come because of similar reasons.

Comment: @oliver I'm also sad that you misunderstand the role of SO, and other SE websites. At its core the role of SO is to help developers find the answers to their problems. But this requires for others to spend time to help them. A poorly written question will waste a lot of time of ones wanting to help, time that could've been spent on questions that askers really spent time making them clear. Downvoting/closing the question is a clear indication the question has problems. It's almost binary :)

Comment: Care to answer this: is it fair for people that ask quality questions to not get answers because the people that can answer them are caught will all kind of other fishy questions, trying to figure out what the heck does the OP need?

Comment: @Cristik: this is a very good question because it is perfect support for my point of view. If those who answer didn't mess around so much with downvoting activity, linking to the site policies and posting irrelevant comments about their own failure to understand what the OP wants and they just ignored what they consider "bad questions", they would have more time available for answering good questions! By being ignored, the "bad questions" would descend in search order automatically.

Comment: @oliver and how would the OP know why his question is ignored? Or why only reputation whores answer it?

Comment: If anyone cares more about the poster of what is silently considered a "bad question" by others he may well do so. And: he may do so without being biased by other people's negative comments. If nobody answers, it is up to the poster to get the attention he wants. But this is all theoretical because most negative comments, let alone the downvotes, are not helpful for the OP anyway.

Comment: @oliver are we talking about negative comments or downvotes? I was discussing about downvotes, malicious comments are another topic. Let's not diverge.

Comment: Actually both because I think neither serves any useful purpose.

Comment: @oliver the question here discusses about question scores. If you want to talk about comments, please open a dedicated question. Otherwise we'll likely end up with a mess, with some people talking about a topic, other people discussing other topic.

Comment: Funny enough, a lot of questions get closed as being too broad for the exact same reason - they try to gets answers to too many things :)

Comment: The question was "why was this question received badly?". The discussion is not messy at all because the downvotes as well as the comments are made by people who don't wanna understand that what they are doing is useless at best. What surprises me a little, that all of you firmly believe in the danger of bad questions for the community. My argument is, that exactly this makes you vulnerable.

Comment: @oliver please show me one nasty comment to the SO question linked by the OP. I kinda feel your pain, however you've chosen a bad example to relate to. Maybe try with another meta post :)

Comment: I was trying to widen the perspective, true. Maybe you can see more clearly than me that all of which I have mentioned is a collection of independent phenomena.

Comment: And to be clear about that, I don't believe that this discussion will change anything (I mentioned that in my answer already), so there is no point in opening another question. I'd be downvoted anyway... see a pattern?

Comment: @oliver likely we have some bad people on SO, however from what I saw so far they are the minority. Most of the people here that engage in comments/answers want to help. Your post kinda says the opposite, and this is why I said earlier that I'm said about it.

Comment: And don't take it that hard about downvotes on meta, here downvotes mean that people don't agree with what you say, not that your post is bad. And this is something you should think on.

Comment: @Cristik: another good point that finally supports me in multiple ways. As you can see in part 2 of my answer, I recommend to the OP to assume the majority of people being friendly. And I am sure it is so. BUT: any impression of all the nice and helpful people here gets distorted by negative votes. AND: negativity is infectious. Why can't you see that?

Comment: So please let's close this discussion, I am tired. I understand your point all too well. But mine is different. Good night. Cheers. :-)

Comment: @oliver I fail to see your point regarding downvotes. On the tags I am active the downvotes are in 90% (or higher) of the cases deserved. Maybe on the tags you watch the situation is different?

Comment: Okay one last feedback: why is it so important that bad questions get what they "deserve". This sounds a little like you think, it is possible to pull yourself up by dragging somebody else down. Again: if a question is effectively equal to null, why bother about deleting it?

Comment: @oliver, as other people have said before me: votes are feedback. Don't you like getting feedback about something you did? Or are you following by the "no feedback is good feedback" paradigm (hope not)? :)

Comment: No! No feedback is bad enough feedback. Telling somebody why he failed in a constructive manner is also absolutely okay. What I don't like to see (neither in response to other people's questions, nor my own ones) is that people obviously put **a lot** of effort into their question just to get three downvotes and comments like "You're question is confusing". If people lack intellect they should either STFU or at least try to understand what they read.

Comment: @oliver Some things to consider: comments are ephemeral; downvotes are -2 while upvotes are +10. The system is quite good so that it doesn't allow bad people to screw good people.

Comment: Okay, I will try to take on your perspective from now on. Cheers! :-)