# How do I get a constructive answer to my question?

Tags: support, specific-question

Note that the link below refers to a past version of my question.

Ok, I tried asking a question for the first time in SO and I immediately received negative votes without anything constructive.

Here: [How to use InputMethodService using C4droid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57364283/how-to-create-an-input-method-for-android-using-c4droid)

I am used to SE (physics) so I am not a complete beginner regarding how the system works. My question apparently is not good enough. However as I mentioned, I am completely new to Android programming so there is no way for me to tell how to improve my question.

Comment: I don't know how it works in Physics.se, but here on SO commenting on votes is not expected and discouraged.

Comment: I'm not an android expert so I'll hold off answering but your question seems quite broad.  It looks like you are asking multiple questions and the ones you are asking are not very clearly defined.  Questions that do the best on SO are often very specific, with specific objectives.  You seem to have a vague "how do I accomplish this task?  I think it might be related to this class"

Comment: I know nothing of the tags you are asking about, but I see a couple of things: You seem to be asking more than one question. Is reading the content of the first link a requisite to answer your first question? Can you try writing your question so it includes all the necessary information about what you want to do, and what kind of problem did encounter when trying to do what you are trying to do. And again, just ask one question per post, unless they are very intimately related.

Comment: Thanks, I changed my question accordingly. I observe I also get downvotes here which is plain ridiculous.

Comment: Re: the linked question, I'm an Android app developer, but this is the first time I hear about C4droid. From its Play Store page, looks like it's a C/C++ compiler. However, what you wanted to do is related to Android SDK (Java API), and I'm not sure and have never heard if there's a C/C++ linker to Android SDK. Might also help: [Why shouldn't an Android app be written in C/C++ because you “simply prefer to program in C/C++”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13773686/2821954)

Comment: @Exocytosis Not at all, one of the [meta-tag:faq] posts is "Why isn't providing feedback mandatory on downvotes, and why are ideas suggesting such shot down?" We get questions from people more than weekly asking why their question was downvoted without comments, which can be easily answered if they just viewed the most frequently asked questions. Lack of research effort is a downvote reason. Your question also would have been a lot more useful to describe why you believe it is on topic and a good fit for the site, and ask how to improve it, rather than focusing on the votes received.

Comment: @andrew: exactly, I am not sure I can interface with a Java class. Yet this IDE is absolutely capable of producing valid APKs including graphics librairies such as QT or SDL. So I wonder if there is a way to  gain access to this native API too.

Comment: @weegee: this is a Java class, my question is for C++, and this is not covered in the page you link or my own searches.

Comment: @Exocytosis Perhaps an example will be easier to understand rather than my comment. This Meta question was much better received, even though it's the same situation (Main site question needing improvement, downvotes, few or no comments), because it was written in a much more useful way: [Why was my question ill-received?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/363959/7795130)

Answer (score 13):

I'm not familiar with Android or C++, but I can see some issues with your question just as a veteran SO user.

- You reference "a lot of things" from an article you read, but don't enumerate what those things are.
- You mention you're not sure how they relate to C4droid. What is that? Is how they relate to C4droid really your question, or do you have some specific *other* question you want to ask?
- Speaking of another question, you mention

  > Regarding Android manifest, how do I insert it in APK created by C4droid?

  This seems like a specific enough question, but it seems different from what you're asking above. Questions on Stack Overflow really shine when they focus on *one* specific question.

  To that end, "how to insert Android manifest into [an] APOK created by C4droid" might be an answerable question, but it also could be too broad (you'd have to check with subject-matter experts, there). One way to guard against that is to show any code attempts you've already made. Even if this is one you know is blatantly wrong, showing your attempts goes a **long** way toward getting quality help here.

  You can see more info about showing your attempts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time. I changed my question to a simpler one about the class. The problem is not about trying to code, it is about configuring the tools ao I can use a class that originates from Java. So I don't know how to make it work with C++ nor if it is even possible.